# How can Matt Murdock read something that isn't written in Braille?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, daredevil, daredevil-2015

In *Daredevil* season one episode nine(*Speak of the Devil*) Matt visits a warehouse on Pier 81. There's a map on a table in the warehouse, and Matt runs his fingers across it and appears to be reading it. However, the map's not written in Braille, so how is he able to do this?

Comment: His sonar is so high fidelity that he can detect the height difference of the lines due to the ink.  :). Kidding, hence comment, I've not seen that episode.

Answer (score 15):

In the comic books, it has sometimes been stated that his super-senses are so incredible that his hypersensitive fingertips can easily detect the difference between paper-with-ink-printed-on-it and paper-without-ink-on-it. After years of practice, he can quickly recognize familiar words with a sweep of his fingertips across each line of text. (I'm not sure I have any comic books in which he navigates that way by touching a printed map, but I wouldn't be surprised if it's happened at least once or twice when the plot required it.)

I Googled just now, and found an online scan of a few panels which show Matt doing this with an ordinary newspaper he picks up.[image]

Comment: I can feel high-quality ink in some junkmail (it has a definite thickness and it’s smoother than the paper) and laser printers/photocopiers from the 1980’s. But not newpaper. I think newpaper in particular is implausable.  People might have been aware of toner-feel at some time such a use was written, though.

Comment: @JDługosz - Well, that’s just because you’re not Daredevil. ;)

Comment: @JDługosz - right; newspapers are printed using a technique where liquid ink is deposited on the surface and allowed to absorb into the paper, which doesn't actually leave an impression. Similarly inkjets. Laser printers and photocopiers use a solid ink that is fused onto the surface, which leaves them standing slightly above the surface (you can actually get laser printers that intentionally produce 3d surfaces!)  and are usually smoother than the paper. Typewritten and handwritten items would be even easier, but newspapers or any mass-produced printed material would be next-to impossible.

Comment: I think this is just one of those things we're supposed to take on faith as "natural laws are different in a comic book universe." Similar to the way Superman just has to put on a business suit and a pair of glasses, and comb his hair differently, and suddenly nobody can see any significant resemblance between "Superman" and "Clark Kent." :)

Comment: There are people in real life who claim they they can tell the difference due to the difference in heat (black ink absorbing a wider wavelength of light than white ink), but those claims are highly disputed.